# Auth::guard('guard')->user() return null after successfull login and redirecting

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.5, guard

I have 3 guards in my 5.5 laravel project, when I login any guard and dd(Auth::guard('guard')->user()) it works and print user data, but when directing to guard home it logout and dd(Auth::guard('guard')->user()) return null

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, It was in my .env

> APP_URL=http://localhost/erdifny

Edited this line to

> APP_URL=http://localhost

and

> SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost/erdifny

// I removed this line from .env